# How to fit a weibull distribution to data using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy

I am looking to find the best fit weibull parameters to a set of data using Python 3.4.

```
import scipy.stats as ss
list1 = []
list2 = []
for x in range(0, 10):
    list1.append(ss.exponweib.pdf(x, a=1, c=2.09, scale=10.895, loc=0))
    list2.append(ss.weibull_min.pdf(x, c=2.09, loc=0, scale=10.895))
    if list1[x]-list2[x] < .000000001:
        list1[x]=list2[x]

if list1 == list2:
    print("true")

print(ss.distributions.weibull_min.fit(list1, floc=0))
print(ss.distributions.weibull_min.fit(list1, loc=0))
print(ss.distributions.weibull_min.fit(list1, floc=0))
print(ss.distributions.exponweib.fit(list1, 1,1))
print(ss.distributions.exponweib.fit(list1, floc=0, f0=1))
print(ss.distributions.exponweib.fit(list1, floc=0, a=1, f0=1))
```

Everything that I have tried doesn't yield the input parameters and I can't figure out why.

The output of this code is:

```
true
(2.8971366871403661, 0, 0.065615284314998634)
(0.71134622938358294, 0.014105558832066645, 0.076662586739229072)
(2.8971366871403661, 0, 0.065615284314998634)
(0.27753056922336583, 3.1962672780921197, -3.4788071110631162e-27, 0.077986010645321888)
(1, 2.8971366871403661, 0, 0.065615284314998634)
(1, 2.8971366871403661, 0, 0.065615284314998634)
```

None of which are the correct input parameters. (2.09 and 10.895.) Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first argument to the `fit()` method is a sample of values from the distribution to be fit (not PDF values).  So you should use the `rvs()` method to generate your data, not the `pdf()` method.

Here's a simple example where I generate a sample of 250 values from the `exponweib` distribution, and then use `fit()` on that sample.  I'll assume that when I fit the data, I know that that the shape parameter `a` must be 1 and the `loc` parameter must be 0:

```
In [178]: from scipy.stats import exponweib

In [179]: sample = exponweib.rvs(a=1, c=2.09, scale=10.895, loc=0, size=250)

In [180]: exponweib.fit(sample, floc=0, fa=1)
Out[180]: (1, 2.0822583185068915, 0, 10.946962241403902)
```